# What do I need to library or require in order to use the phantom() function?

Tags: r

I am a bit of an R newbie, and this seems like a stupidly obvious question.  But please don't flame me, I've tried searching and can't find the obvious answer.  The R documentation says plotmath {grDevices}.  plotmath is not a library as far as I can tell, but grDevices is.  So including it does allow for ?phantom, but any call to phantom gets the error 'could not find function "phantom"'.  What am I missing?

Comment: You can also find out if `phantom` is an R function with `any(ls('package:grDevices') == "phantom")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many of R's graphical devices "understand" a special TeX-like mini-language that allows users to describe rudimentary mathematical expressions that they would like included in a plot.

`phantom()` looks like an R function call, but is really a part of that minilanguage, which is documented in more detail in `?plotmath`. As a result, it only makes sense to R when it's used in an expression passed in as argument to a function that "speaks plotmath".

Here is an example of how you might use it in practice:

```
plot(1, main = expression(paste(r^2==0.9230, ",  ", P<phantom(), "0.0001")))
```